# 名詞になる versus 名詞する versus 名詞だ

Tags: grammar

I noticed there are certain nouns that can be used in  名詞になる, 名詞する, and 名詞だ forms.

For example:

彼女が・妊娠・うんざり・怪我・看護師・うつ伏せ・している。

彼女が・妊娠・うんざり・怪我・看護師・うつ伏せ・になっている。

彼女が・妊娠・うんざり・怪我・看護師・うつ伏せ・だ。

She is pregnant/bored/injured/a nurse/lying face down.

I seem to me that the nouns in this case must represent physical states. Correct me if I am wrong.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have seen all of these combinations? They don't even belong to the same word class.

看護師 is a plain noun that can be used with する/やる/なる. It's not a suru-verb:

> - 彼女は看護師(を)している。 She works as a nurse. (を can be dropped only in a very casual sentence)
> - 彼女が看護師になっている。 She has become a nurse.
> - 彼女が看護師だ。 She is a/the nurse. (exhaustive-listing *ga*)

妊娠/うんざり/怪我 is a suru-verb. 妊娠/怪我 [optionally takes を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5010).

> - 彼女が妊娠している。 She is pregnant.
> - 彼女が妊娠になっている。 (makes little sense to me unless you want to say "she's got a pregnant/disgusted/injured condition" in a game context, etc)
> - 彼女が妊娠だ。 (not entirely impossible, but sounds blunt or clumsy)

うつ伏せ is a no-adjective.

> - 彼女がうつ伏せしている。  (ungrammatical)
> - 彼女がうつ伏せになっている。 She is lying face down.
> - 彼女がうつ伏せだ。 She is lying face down.

See: [Replacing になっている with だ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13077/5010)